# How to select and delete a column of text in emacs?

Tags: region, rectangle, kill-text

I have this text

```
1 A
2 B
3 C
```

I want to remove the first column to make it

```
A
B
C
```

Ok so I need to make a rectangle. Reading about [rectangles](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Rectangles.html) I see

"To specify a rectangle for a command to work on, set the mark at one corner and point at the opposite corner. The rectangle thus specified is called the region-rectangle. If point and the mark are in the same column, the region-rectangle is empty. If they are in the same line, the region-rectangle is one line high."

I go to line 1 column 1 and set the mark with C-SPC. I go to the end of the rectangle at line 3 column 2 (to include column 1 only). Then I do C-w. It kills everything up to C:

```
 C
```

Obviously it included columns 2 and 3. How to prevent this and only select column 1?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`C-w` kills the text between point and mark; it’s the normal command you would use to kill text. `C-x r k` kills the *rectangle* between point and mark. This is the one you want to use.

Answer (score 18):

If you *select* the rectangle, which in Emacs terms means make it an *active* rectangular region, then `C-w` does just what you expect.

Use **`C-x SPC`** to activate a rectangular region that you want to kill. Then just use `C-w`, the usual key for killing the active region.

To select a rectangular region, do one of the following:

- Put point and mark at opposite corners (the same thing you'd need to do to be able to use `C-x r k`) and then hit `C-x SPC`.
- Use `C-x SPC` first (that activates an empty rectangular region), and then move point to the opposite corner, extending the selection as you move the cursor.
- Drag `C-M-mouse-1` to select the rectangle. (Thanks to @pst for pointing this out in a comment here.) For this, you need Emacs 27 or later.

Comment: Or, select that rectangular region by pressing Ctrl + Meta while selecting with mouse-1. Then use normal C-w (or DEL) for killing the region.
(Question didn't say "... from the keyboard", so I think it's good to mention this way as well.)

Comment: @pst: Good point. I've added that to the answer. If you prefer, you can post it separately as an answer and I'll remove if from this answer. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

If you use evil, I've found `evil-visual-block` bound to `C-v` to be the most straightforward.

- `C-v` to enter visual block mode
- Arrows (or preferred movement) to select column/rectangular region
- `d` delete